# CakePhp Errors (set 404 page)

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp

When I go to http://www.xxxy.com/wp-login.php without a slash at the end, I have the 404 not found page.
When I add a slash (http://www.xxxy.com/wp-login.php/), the website appears and is totally broken.

In my AppController I have this:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->_setErrorLayout();
    parent::beforeFilter();
}

public function _setErrorLayout() {
    if ($this->name == 'CakeError') {
        $this->layout = 'error';
    }
}
```

Do you know what is wrong when we have an extra slash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the HTML source, you're using relative paths for all your assets.

```
<link href="css/media.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<img src="images/logo.png" alt=""/>
```

Adding a trailing slash makes `wp-login.php` appear to be a folder, and consequently `css/media.css` becomes `/wp-login.php/css/media.css`, which of course doesn't exist.

You should use absolute paths like `/css/media.css`, which btw. is what the CakePHP HTML helpers normally generate automatically when used properly.

See also **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html**

ps. it's a good idea to allow only either the slashed, or the unslashed version, but that's a different subject.

Comment: Hoooo I see now ... I will check that better, thanks :)